# Как передать массив по ссылке? PHP

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста как передать массив php по ссылке? 
Итак, есть массив:

```
$array = ["Петрушка", "Малина", "Клубника", "Апельсин"];
```

Как передать его по ссылке? Когда использую такой вариант:

```
<a href="site.ru?array=<?$array?>"</a>
```

Ничего не происходит, пытаюсь вывести на странице куда направляется линк:

```
print_r($array);
```

Но ничего не происходит. Подскажите, пожалуйста как отправить массив и вывести его на странице?

Comment: Попробуй <a href="site.ru?array=<? echo implode(",",$array);?>"</a>

Comment: А именно массивом нельзя передать, чтоб можно было выводить типо так:  echo $array[0];?

Comment: нельзя. то что передается в параметрах ссылки должно быть строкой. а массив это объект в php. думаю невелик труд написать $array=explode(",",$_GET['array']); echo $array[0];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у вас есть пара вариантов решения задачи. первый уже описанный в комментариях и ответе Эдуарда - кодирование массива в строку любым доступным способом. После этого еще желателен url_encode. На стороне сервера, декодирование из строки.

Второй вариант, чтобы на стороне сервера получить данные в виде массива, формат параметров должен быть вида `?data[]=value1&data[]=value2` тогда `$_GET['data']` будет массивом со значениями `0 => 'value1', 1 => 'value2'`

```
<?php 
  print_r($_GET['data']);

?>
<a href="?data[]=Петрушка&data[]=Малина">test</a>
```

вдогонку,
под ваш вопрос идеальным (с точки зрения близости к вопросу, а не реализации) ответом будет использование `http_build_query()`.

```
<a href="?<?= http_build_query(['array' => ["Петрушка", "Малина", "Клубника", "Апельсин"]]) ?>">test</a>
```

Comment: скобок не хватает в http_build_query

Comment: @Naumov, да, добавил

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи массива можно преобразовать его в строку, а после приёма снова преобразовать в массив:

```
<?php

var_dump( explode(' ', $_GET['array'] ?? null) );
$array = ["Петрушка", "Малина", "Клубника", "Апельсин"];

?>

<a href="?array=<?= join(' ', $array) ?>">Линк</a>
```